# EF: Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework with my WEB Api project.
I use code first migration.

The thing is:  After making my intitial migration and trying to update database, I get this error

> Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order

Which is caused by this SQL command in update database:

```
create table `Articles` 
(
 `articleId` int not null  auto_increment ,
 `title` longtext not null ,
 `digest` longtext,
 `content` longtext not null ,
 `imgLink` longtext not null ,
 `releaseDate` datetime,
 `userId` int not null ,
  primary key ( `articleId`)
) engine=InnoDb auto_increment=0
  CREATE index  `IX_userId` on `Articles` (`userId` DESC) using HASH
```

The SQL command is generated from this code in migration:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Articles",
            c => new
                {
                    articleId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    title = c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false),
                    digest = c.String(unicode: false),
                    content = c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false),
                    imgLink = c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false),
                    releaseDate = c.DateTime(precision: 0),
                    userId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.articleId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.userId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.userId);
```

Seems like DESC and HASH on the index creation cause this error. 
Any ideas on how to change the generated sql Index creation so it goes with a simple indexation ? Or just simply bypass this error so my update-database can go through ? Thank you !

**EDIT:** added article class

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        this.comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int articleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public string digest { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string imgLink { get; set; }

    public DateTime? releaseDate { get; set; }

    // Clé étrangère (table User)
    public int userId { get; set; }

    // Auteur de l'article
    public virtual User user { get; set; }

    // Commentaires
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> comments { get; set; }
}
```

I'll add that DESC HASH on index is generated in output of every .Index() in migration file

Comment: Hi, if you are using data annotations; can you show the entity Article?

Comment: @Stefan just added it

Comment: Hmm... too bad... it looks fine

Comment: Any ideas on why Indexes are generated this way ? I tried to remove the indexes from the migration file but obviously I can't get my articles then

Comment: I tried to replace .Index in migration to a raw SQL (removing the HASH only, rest of the cmd is the same). No more hash index error, but my Get controllers does not work then.. (Can't gather comments, saying DataReader is already open and need to be close first) Feelsbad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it.

In your migration file, replace .Index entries by sql commands like below

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.Articles",
        c => new
            {
                articleId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                title = c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false),
                digest = c.String(unicode: false),
                content = c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false),
                imgLink = c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false),
                releaseDate = c.DateTime(precision: 0),
                userId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.articleId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.userId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.userId); // REMOVE THIS
```

Add the corresponding SQL command at the bottom of your Up() method (for every index)

```
Sql("CREATE index `IX_userId` on `Articles` (`userId` DESC)");
```

The problems I add then with DataReaders are MySQL connector related. MySQL connector doesn't support multiple active connections. To handle this, if you had this in your controller

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles()
{
    return db.Articles;
}
```

Now it should be

```
public IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles()
{
    return db.Articles.ToList(); // ToList() will manage the request to work with only ONE data reader, 
}
```

If you don't know how to convert your .Index() to SQL commands, just

```
update-database -verbose
```

and all the SQL commands will show